# Launch Konsole with specific window title

Tags: konsole, title

Ubuntu 22.04, kde plasma

Hi, I'd like to find a way to launch konsole from within a bash script and have it open with a user-specified window title. No interaction. Just a command to open a konsole window with "This is Jack's konsole" as its title.

Thank you!

(Or some other terminal emulator that provides this functionality.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set name of Konsole window](https://superuser.com/questions/705898/set-name-of-konsole-window)

Comment: @harrymc, I found one more way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start new Konsole and set title one simple way is to run the program on this way:

```
Konsole --tabs-from-file filename
```

where `filename` contain:

```
title: "This is Jack's konsole"
```

Comment: Well . . . my file (konsole_title_jackd) contains 
"title: running_htop;; command: /usr/bin/htop"
and when I run:

"konsole --tabs-from-file konsole_title_jackd"

Nothing happens. I have no prompt, which would be normal if the command was running something, but I see nothing, no terminal windows open. 

"ps -ef" shows:
"kpov_te+   71110    3916  1 12:45 pts/4    00:00:00 konsole --tabs-from-file konsole_title_jackd"

So something is running somewhere, but it ain't visible. I hit Ctrl-C to get back to prompt.